# Use Verbose when building with Webpack and NPM

Tags: npm, webpack

I have the following package.json file and I am building using webpack:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "4.21.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

How can I pass a parameter when using `npm run build` to use `verbose` so I can see build errors?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the following:

`npm run build --verbose`

(you can pass any parameter via `npm run <command>` after `--`).

Comment: We know from the official documentation that build does not have a verbose argument, the answer is wrong. I don't know why this answer is marked as correct.

Comment: I can validate that this answer is wrong for Webpack 5, it fails the build on

Comment: i see `--verbose` in `webpack -h`, but is that `--verbose` passed to npm or webpack?

Comment: Webpack build fails for me with --verbose

Answer (score 5):

You can set the output details level using the stats prop in the webpack config file

```
module.exports = { stats: 'verbose',};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/

Answer (score 4):

To be more clear with regards to the first answer, using `npm run build --verbose` does increase the log level of the *npm process*, as noted here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/logging. This does not necessarily bump any log level in the Webpack process itself.

The first answer would incur additional logging for the npm process. The parenthetical note is slightly misleading -- if you want to pass a parameter to an npm script to pass to the underlying scripts, you need to add a primary "--". So, while that answer does increase npm logging, it doesn't necessarily alter the webpack logging verbosity.

For example, if you have a linter scripts in npm:

```
"jest-preview": "jest-preview",
"lint": "eslint ./src",
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development"
```

If you want to utilize the "--fix" parameter to pass to eslint, you would run this npm script as:

```
npm run lint -- --fix
```

As can be seen on https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/, there is no --verbose option for build in webpack-cli. There are some facilities for log output verbosity configuration for the loaders and plugins that can be implemented in the webpack config. I would check that documentation for further information.